# NOD name for VALUE?

Tags: jquery, treenode

I've a few inputs and I want to clear their values after clicking. How to?

```
 <input type="text" value="Name" />
```

I've tried:

```
$(this).inputValue("");
```

But it doesn't work. If I'm unable to change the value, how to add text to the input ($(this).text(""); works very well in, for example, textareas).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.val(newValue)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for setting the value of any input type element (including `<textarea>` and `<select>`), like this:

```
$("input:text").click(function() {
  $(this).val(""); 
});
```

Comment: Where can I find all the names of nod elements for JS/jQuery? I mean I was trying with value/inputvalue, but it's val. is there a list of shortcuts?

Comment: @fomicz - The official API site here: http://api.jquery.com/ easy to search for what you're after :)